# Type My location in place autocomplete API android

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

Does android place autocomplete API contains the My location as a suggestion which takes the user location as input.

Comment: Posted same in Android stack exchange

Answer (score -1):

If I read your question correctly, you want to pass the current location as input to the autocomplete service. The autocomplete service does not return the current device location. https://devsite.googleplex.com/places/android-api/current-place shows how to get the current location, and return a list of likely nearby places.

Comment: What's the link. It takes to login page.

Comment: @dubnewt please paste relevant links here